# Find out what's disabling screenshots

Tags: screenshots

My nexus 5x with cyanogenmod doesn't let me take screenshots anymore, telling me that either some app is disabling them or there is no space left.
As i have enough disk space, some app or system setting must be the problem.

I do not know of any new app since the last time i took screenshots, which would disable this and now i cannot even screenshot the home screen.

Is there an option to find out, what's disabling the screenshot function?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Seems to be a bug with file permissions (owner looks corrent, possibly selinux?).

Remove or rename the Screenshots folder, see https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/cant-take-screenshots.78176/page-2#post-7449160.

Answer (score 0):

I just requested desktop site on browser, log in and screen shot will work (so far).  Forget the apps, I've uninstalled most of them and just log in on my browser of choice (Samsung beta will work on just about Android phone and even has a secret mode).